# Создать Host WCF

Tags: хост, клиент-сервер, wcf

Необходимо создать хост для клиент-серверного приложения

```
Type serviceType = typeof(Container);
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
```

Но `Container` у меня представлен статическим классом [`ServiceContract`]. Там есть свойство, обозначенное [`DataMember`] и метод, обозначенный [`OperationContract`]. Скажите, могу ли я использовать такую структуру, потому что постоянно получаю ошибку "В `ContractDescription "Container"` нет операций.". Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у вас есть

```
public static class Container
 {
    public static string Prop { get; set; }

    public static void Method()
    {

    }
 }
```

Использовать в таком виде не получится т.к. инфраструктура WCF создает экзепмляр объекта, а создать экземпляр статического класса  не получится.

Если нужен единственный экземпляр для всех вызовов то это можно сделать используя настройку ServiceBehavior InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single

Также необходимо объявить контракт сервиса в виде интерфейса операций, без него тоже никак не обойтись

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IContainerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetProperty();
    [OperationContract]
    void Method();
}
```

Далее создать реализацию данного контракта сервиса, если нельзя отрефакторить Container то можно его вызовы обернуть в реализацию

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
// экземпляр ContainerService будет создан один раз и 
// использоваться для       всех подключений
public class ContainerService : IContainerService
{
    public string GetProperty()
    {
        return Container.Prop;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Container.Method();
    }
}
```